# Binding Generic Object (List<T>) to Custom Xamarin Control

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin.forms, pagination

I am developing a mobile app that has an API that I can call to get data, the majority of the endpoints are paged and return the following object:

```
public class PagedResult<T>
{
    public List<T> Data { get; private set; }

    public PagingInfo Paging { get; private set; }

    public PagedResult(IEnumerable<T> items, int pageNo, int pageSize, long totalRecordCount)
    {
        Data = new List<T>(items);
        Paging = new PagingInfo
        {
            PageNo = pageNo,
            PageSize = pageSize,
            TotalRecordCount = totalRecordCount,
            PageCount = totalRecordCount > 0
                ? (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecordCount / (double)pageSize)
                : 0
        };
    }
}
```

I have built a control that can select the paged results, the control presents a list of the current page items & allows the user to move through the other pages (pictured below).

[image: The pagination control I built]

I have built a proof of concept for this control however I have run into a small but really annoying stumbling block.

My `PagedResult<T>` is generic, but the `PagedItemSource` for my list view is not. I built the control to have the bindable properties: `DataTemplate`, `PagedItemSource` & `LoadPageCommand`. The control itself determines which page gets loaded & will execute that command itself (I may expose this value later but it's not needed for now).

When building the control I had to initialise the `PagedResult<T>`, however instead of worrying about generics I just made it into `PagedResult<object>` and did the same in my view model. Now i'm at the point where I want this list to be generic, part of the reason I built this control was to be generic and abstract as much responsibility for the paging to the control. However due to the fact that my API model uses a generic, I've gotten stuck!

I cannot initialise my control with a Generic T:

```
public partial class PaginationControl<T>: ContentView
{
    ...
}
```

Will mean that the C# compiler starts shouting at me, the whole class goes beserk in fact. My binded properties display the warning: `Static field in generic type`. This is why I just used `<object>` as the type of my list, unfortunately the binding won't work in the following scenario:

**View Model**

```
public PagedResult<MyObject> PagedItemSource { get; set; }
```

**Control**

```
public static readonly BindableProperty PagedItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(PagedItemSource),
    typeof(PagedResult<object>),
    typeof(PaginationControl),
    defaultValue: null,
    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => ((PaginationControl)bindable).OnPagedItemSourceChanged((PagedResult<object>)newVal)
);
```

*It will work if my view model's data is also of type `<object>` however thats no use because now I need to track the type of my data in my view model...*

I've come up with a hacky work around so that I can crack on with the app, but it's stupid and feels dirty and I hate it...

*My hack is to have a second property in my view model which just takes the current `PagedResult<T>` and converts it to `PagedResult<object>`, and binding this property to the control. (Sorry you had to read this)*

I went and had a trawl for the Xamarin.Forms source code to see how they did this for `ListView` since it's essentially the same issue & their `ListView` accepts any generic object. Unfortunately I found the src incredibly confusing and learned nothing that would help solve my issue (I saw in `ItemView<Cell>` that `ItemSource` is an `IEnumerable` but I couldnt figure out how they were setting the `T` of this...

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm probably looking at this in the wrong way!

Comment: Why would you ever make a control generic? `ItemsSource` properties are always non-generic `System.Collections.IEnumerable`; there is no type parameter there. Anything generic should go in the viewmodel. XAML bindings are "duck typed": `ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"` means "I don't care what type DataContext is, just try to find any random property on it named MyItems. If there is one, and if the value returned by that property implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` either implicitly or explicitly, populate yourself with whatever random objects the enumerator gives you".

Comment: That is the beauty and magic of XAML.

Comment: Hi @EdPlunkett. I understand your point, my xaml control should need to care about the item's that are bound to it. My issue is that since I've abstracted my binding to `PagedResult<T>` I cannot figure out how I can advertise that as a valid bindable property. By using `PagedResult<object>` as the property on my control, I cannot bind a `PagedResult<UserDetails>` to the controls, I would have to first convert the type to be of `object`, which adds the very boilerplate into my viewmodel I was trying to avoid by creating this control that handled the lions share of the paging :/

Comment: OK, so the generic properties/methods you've added to your control? Identify all of them and delete them from the source file. Then restart Visual Studio so you can't be tempted to hit Undo. Then write a generic viewmodel that does what you need, and make that the control's DataContext. I've done this quite a few times. You were onto something in your question when you wondered if you're looking at this the wrong way. Does Xamarin support implicit datatemplates? If so, and you want to use them (they're handy), I'll show you how. It's a snap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ed Plunkett already mentioned you're thinking about the wrong way.

`ItemsSource` is of type `IEnumerable` there's no generic argument there since the `ListView` does not care about the specific type of items. This should be the case for your control as well, otherwise you wouldn't make it generic.

So why not just follow the same design they implement for most collections, `List<T>` for example also implements `IList<T>` and `IList` as interfaces. the last interface can be used when you're not interested in the generic argument but just want access to the list. Following this setup we can make something like this:

```
public interface IPagedResult
{
    IEnumerable Data { get; }

    PagingInfo Paging { get; }

    //any other properties you might need
}
```

Then we can declare `PagedResult` like this:

```
public class PagedResult<T> : IPagedResult
{
    public List<T> List { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable Data => List;

    public PagingInfo Paging { get; private set; }

    public PagedResult(IEnumerable<T> items, int pageNo, int pageSize, long totalRecordCount)
    {
        List = new List<T>(items);
        Paging = new PagingInfo
        {
            PageNo = pageNo,
            PageSize = pageSize,
            TotalRecordCount = totalRecordCount,
            PageCount = totalRecordCount > 0
                ? (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecordCount / (double)pageSize)
                : 0
        };
    }
}
```

And now you should just be able to declare your `BindableProperty` like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty PagedItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(PagedItemSource),
    typeof(IPagedResult),
    typeof(PaginationControl),
    defaultValue: null,
    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => ((PaginationControl)bindable).OnPagedItemSourceChanged((IPagedResult)newVal)
);
```

And from this bindable property you can access the data list but also the paging information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow ok great explanation. I looked through some controls I made in another project and I used `IList` there, total dunce moment from me! I've implemented your suggestions and everything works exactly as I intended it to! Thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. Good luck with the project!